# How come other languages can call .net6 dll's, but a .net framework application cannot?

Tags: c#, dll, .net-6.0

We have a very large .net 4.8 application, and would like to start creating newer features in .net 6 as separate libraries in an attempt to slowly upgrade everything. However it seems that .net Framework cannot call .net 6 dll's!

However I believe other languages, such as VB, can call a DLL of any version. So why does .net framework care so much?

Am i missing something?

Comment: I'm guessing it might be because that would require two separate CLRs to be hosted in the same process.

Comment: What you _can_ do is write Libraries in .NetStandard, so you can use them in different Runtimes. Or you can have multiple targets, but then the code must support that. Which is probably not what you want, as I read this.

Comment: If you meant classic VB then it can use any unmanaged dll that is following the standard of unmanaged dlls. Assemblies are not those dlls.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError yeah actually does make sense actually... damn it.
Fildor yeah exactly, wanted to keep it .net 6 only ideally... but starting to look like thats not going to be possible. And porting the existing 4.8 application to 6 is just not a viable option at the moment :(

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. A .NET Framework (4.X) application cannot call into a .NET 6.0+ assembly. But the other way round works most of the time. So if you change your main app to compile with .NET 6.0, you can reference .NET 4.X assemblies or Nugets. You might get a bunch of warnings that the old libraries are not fully compatible, but you can still try to run them.

Note that you always run only one instance of the runtime, so within one process, there can only be one version of the .NET runtime, but the binary code of .NET Framework and .NET libraries is the same and the system libraries are mostly backwards compatible.